# BigQuery getting resource exceeded during query execution issue on query that worked yesterday

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I have a very unusual situation that arose over the last 48 hours. I am dealing with a BigQuery SQL query that is currently getting a "Resources exceeded during execution" error. The query has run successfully on a CRON for a number of months and died about 48 hours ago. Below is a snapshot of the query:

[image: Failed Query]

The job ID is shown above, and is: model-folio-818.job_dEdyeaHonw2PWz2z0jVVgBekGsg

Has anyone noticed anything unusual over the last few days that has impacted their queries? The BigQuery instance is currently running the production data warehouse environment and hence the breakdown is causing major angst. Any insight from anyone here on similar changes or the Google team would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: We'll take a look. Note that one-off issues are better posted to the issue tracker here: https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. I threw the issue through Google Premium support but hadn't heard back. The DW has been down for 48 hours which is causing some angst & hence I raised it here. Will pop future issues on the issue tracker or use IRC. Thanks again!

Comment: Yep, initial investigation suggests that this is a bug in a release that rolled out a few days ago. We'll try to patch things up soon.

Comment: Great & thanks Jeremy. Keep me posted on the timing as the DW will be grounded until this goes back up. Have a fantastic night!

Comment: Unfortunately a rollback did not help, so we suspect this has to do with skewed data in the tables you're querying. Did you make any changes to your data that might have tipped the scales? Are there particular join key or group key values that have a disproportionately large number of rows?